# Can you export protocol types to instal on the live enviroment?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have successfully setup our first interface on our development environment. when we try to put this live, we get an error stating that "Protocol type "WCF-Custom" not found.". At first we tought this was due to the adapter not being installed on the live but we assured ourselves that this is the case. the only diffrence between the two enviroments now is the fact that we deployed to the test one and are importing the exported msi on the live. Is there a way to also import this protocol?

Comment: Strange!. Just some ideas. Does the WCF-Custom adapter appear in the list of Adapters? (under Platform Settings / Adapters / WCF-Custom)
If you try and create a request/response receive port, does WCF-Custom appear in the list?
Make sure that there are send and receive handlers (i.e. BizTalk Host instances) assigned to the adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most often caused by not having the WCF Adapter installed. It may be worthwhile to go and and uninstall and reinstall it.

Note also that you have to both **import** the MSI file into BizTalk and **run** the MSI file on the live server.

Lastly, verify in the BizTalk Server Administration Console that the WCF-Custom adapter is assigned to a valid BizTalk host, which has a host instance assigned to it. The adapter needs to have a handler for both send and receive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the adapter is visible under Platform Settings - Adapter. If it is not there, add it.(After running all the MSI's to install the adapters.) This is what I had to do to get rid of this error. (Except mine said it could not find WCF-SQL in stead of WCF-Custom.)